# Java RS-232 Communication on Windows

Tags: java, windows, serial-port

Does anyone know of a good Java API for controlling RS-232 devices in a WIN32 enviroment?
I've tried RXTX but they don't support RS232, only RS-485.

Answer (score 5):

Without reservation, I recommend Java Serial Port from [serialio.com](http://serialio.com). I had significant stability problems with the Sun, IBM and RxTx serial packages.  SerialPort has been rock solid in production for over 2 years 24/7.

They support the standard Java serial API, as well as their own alternative proprietary one.  I would stick with the standard API though, unless you really need something theirs has that the standard one doesn't, just to keep your options open.

Comment: word! serialio is it worth, really!

Comment: I should, in fairness, point out that my project was done a little over 2 years ago, and RxTx may have progressed since then.

Comment: The quality of the RXTX code is quite bad. Be prepared to jump through various hoops if you go down this road.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to try jSSC. This lib support Win32(Win98 - Win7) and Win64. Linux version under construction. Project page on Google code: http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Comment: Does jSSC support RS-422 as well as RS-232?

Answer (score 2):

What about [J/CoMM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcomm/)?

> OS independent RS232 remote control. Java-based server (console), easy adjustable HTML GUI, local/internet use, incl. device driver API and drivers (e.g. EIKI LC-XM1/SM1/VM1!!)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented a single-direction interface (device->computer) with Scream3r's jSSC library using Java 1.6 and Windows 7 64 bit quickly and without problems.

Hint: If you look at his additional code in jSSC-Terminal.zip you get a nice (and essential for using the lib) example how to work with the library!

Thank you Scream3r for sharing this, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon scm which is another open source library for RS232 serial port communication. Project page is https://github.com/RishiGupta12/serial-communication-manager

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried [Javacomm](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/) from Sun?

Comment: Javacomm doesn't support Windows anymore.  On their main page, they don't even list it.  More searching reveals that Sun dropped support for it after Java 1.1.6