# Is there Java library or framework for accessing Serial ports?

Tags: java, serial-port

Is there a java library or framework (other than the javax.comm provided by Sun) that is easy to use when accessing serial and parallel ports ( especially RS-232 ).
I need something free that will work both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264469/java-rs-232-communication-on-windows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As andri pointed out [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/) is pretty much your best choice. There is an article on [getting started with RXTX on Windows here](http://kuligowski.pl/java/rs232-in-java-for-windows,1) (relating to RXTX 2.1).

Answer (score 12):

The most common framework used for this is [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/).

Answer (score 5):

If free isn't necessary -- remember, your time isn't free -- then [Serial IO SerialPort](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php/) might be useful. It's the only thing I found that works as-is on all of the following:

- 32/64-bit Windows
- 64-bit Solaris (didn't test 32-bit)
- 32 bit Linux (didn't test 64-bit)
- Mac OS X

You do get source with the product, albeit with some weird and annoying build practices.

FWIW, I'm just a contented user, not affiliated with the company.

Comment: I have used it also with multiple versions of Windows with no problems - OTOH, serial libraries from Sun, IBM and RxTx were all unstable and crashed at random intervals.

Answer (score 0):

rxtx as the other posters have said. I've been using it and it works nicely. There is a problem if using nonstandard highspeed baudrates (multiples of 115200 e.g. 230400, 921600 are OK, but 1MB is not even if the hardware & underlying OS supports it), I've been told this will be corrected in rxtx 2.2.

Comment: Hi, would you still recommend rxtx? Since it's still at 2.1 and not having fixed the bug you mentioned 6 years ago.

Comment: Not really; there's Trent and maybe a few other contributors, and it still has the same problems. I use purejavacomm now; have been using it with 4.3Mbaud with an FTDI chip with high success.