# Reading data from a unix device

Tags: java, unix, device

On one of my RedHat Linux Servers a couple devices have been setup. /dev/ap and /dev/reuter. They are AP and Reuters news feeds. At the unix command line I can do "cat /dev/ap" and it waits until a message comes down the feed and prints it out to stdout. As soon as there is a pause in the stream cat completes. I tried "more" and got the same results, same with less -f (complete msg, could be luck) and tail -f had no output in an hour.

I know these are streams, but when I try to open a Java BufferReader on new Reader("/dev/ap") I get no output. Using the following run method:

```
public void run() {
    String line = null;
    while(true) {
        try {
            while((line = bsr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Couple questions:
1. Are some of the unix commands limited to opening streams from files? e.g. tail?
2. What Am I doing wrong on the Java side that I can't capture the output?
Wrong stream type, wrong wrapper type?
Jim

Comment: How are you actually initializing `bsr`?  You're certainly not doing it the way you say you are.

Comment: What do you get as the output of "ls -l /dev/ap"?

Comment: BufferedReader bsr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/dev/ap")

Comment: ls -l /dev/ap shows that it is a link to /dev/ttyaa02

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach seems sound, but [`readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) is very particular about what constitutes a line of text. You might look at the raw stream:

```
cat /dev/ap | hexdump -C
```

You could also try [`read()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29), as seen in this fragment that reads from `/dev/zero`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/dev/zero"));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(in.read() + " ");
}
System.out.println();
in.close();
```

Addendum: For serial I/O, consider [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264469) libraries.

Comment: Apparently, need to treat this dev as a serial port which requires javacomm.

Comment: @Jim Jones: It's never easy. :-) I've added some links above.

Comment: Yah in fact, I think I'll have to use RXTX because it is a virtual serial port.