# Easiest way to read a String from a RS-232 port?

Tags: java

I have a custom made board which reads different metrics from various sensors (e.g. temperature in Celcius, pressure in bars) and sends them by a RS-232 port as a string with a "channel" (a mnemonic of the sensor) and the actual reading e.g. "a14.23" or "b33.0".

I need to read and parse that info in java and send it to a JMS queue for further processing in another app. The requirement is that it MUST work on Windows XP/7.

I was reading that Oracle Java Communications API is implemented just for Linux/Solaris Systems so this discards it for this project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264469/java-rs-232-communication-on-windows

Comment: One search later:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an old version of the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).